# после установки Яндекс Метрика, Google пишет ошибку значение "FID" слишком велико: более 300 мс

Tags: pagespeed-insights, яндекс-метрика

После установки счетчика Яндекс метрика на сайт  возрастает:
 "Макс. потенц. задержка после первого ввода (FID)" 
(с 110 мс до до 300 мс)

до установки счетчика https://prnt.sc/qdn20r
после установки счетчика https://prnt.sc/qdmzp5

После чего Google пишет ошибку на всех статьях с Яндекс Метрикой: 
"Значение показателя "FID" слишком велико: более 300 мс (мобильные устройства)"
https://prnt.sc/qdn3y9

И выкидывает эти  статьи из индекса (поиска)

(и это я еще перенес tag.js на свой сервак, то так FID писало 460 мс)

Помогите решить проблему, то не возможно использовать Яндекс Метрику.

Answer (score 0):

Отключайте Вэбвизор 2.0, в нем основная проблема. Результат сразу будет заметен. 
Много людей пишут в поддержку Яндекса, но ничего за год не исправлено.

Дискусия: [Скрипт метрики (tag.js) съедает процессорное время при загрузке](https://yandex.ru/blog/metrika-club/skript-metriki-tag-js-sedaet-protsessornoe-vremya-pri-zagruzke).

Answer (score 0):

Ставьте метрику в скрипт, который будет запускать ее только после начала скроллинга страницы и все будет окей.